Running Quantum Espresso from ASE
On my Windows Subsystem for Linux I compiled QE and I can execute simple test script from terminal. However, if I try to run QE using ASE I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/PhD/DFT/ASE_test/Untitled.py", line 60, in <module>
    energy_h2 = run_espresso(h2, 'H2')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/mnt/d/PhD/DFT/ASE_test/Untitled.py", line 41, in run_espresso
    calc = Espresso(pseudopotentials=pseudopotentials, tstress=True, tprnfor=True, input_data=input_parameters, kpts=(1, 1, 1))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mateja/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/calculators/espresso.py", line 165, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/mateja/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ase/calculators/genericfileio.py", line 274, in __init__
    raise BadConfiguration(f'No configuration of {template.name}')
ase.calculators.calculator.BadConfiguration: No configuration of espresso

Here is the python code:
from ase import Atoms
from ase.build import molecule
from ase.calculators.espresso import Espresso
import subprocess

qe_bin_path = '~/qe-7.3.1/bin'  
pseudo_dir = '/mnt/d/PhD/DFT/SSSP_1.3.0_PBE_efficiency'

input_parameters = {
    'control': {
        'calculation': 'scf',
        'prefix': 'H2',
        'pseudo_dir': pseudo_dir,
        'outdir': './out',
    },
    'system': {
        'ecutwfc': 30,
        'ecutrho': 240,
    },
    'electrons': {
        'conv_thr': 1e-8,
    }
}

pseudopotentials = {
    'H': 'H.pbe-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF'  # Ensure this file is in the pseudo_dir
}

def run_espresso(atoms, prefix):
    input_parameters['control']['prefix'] = prefix
    calc = Espresso(pseudopotentials=pseudopotentials, tstress=True, tprnfor=True, input_data=input_parameters, kpts=(1, 1, 1))

    input_file = f'{prefix}.in'
    output_file = f'{prefix}.out'
    calc.write_input(atoms, inputfile=input_file)
    
    mpirun_command = f'mpirun -np 2 pw.x -in {input_file} > {output_file}'
    subprocess.run(mpirun_command, shell=True, check=True)

    calc.read_results()
    return atoms.get_potential_energy()

h2 = molecule('H2')
energy_h2 = run_espresso(h2, 'H2')
```


+1. Welcome to our community.

Apparently python got confused about ~ symbol. Putting whole path instead of qe_bin_path = '~/qe-7.3.1/bin' solves the problem

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I guess you are using the latest version of ase, in which the calculator requests an additional input "profile".

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
